# Eclipse RCP not showing in Plugin registry

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I am developing a simple RCP application. I am referring multiple sources in web and I am adding few UI entities like menu, splash screen,intro window etc. But some of my changes are not getting reflected while I launch my application. For example, the menu and splash image are not working but intro window works well. I referred the tutorial here http://www.eclipse-tips.com/tutorials/16. Here author has explained about manually restarting the plugins to get the new changes reflected. But my plugin is not all showing in plugin registry view. Can some one help me.

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using? There are some bugs like https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=81322 that werent't solved before 3.5

Comment: I am using Eclipse Helios (3.6). So I don't think it is a bug.

Comment: Have you specified your custom product id in your Eclipse application launch configuration instead of just using the eclipse platform or SDK product id?